# Scala: Matching case classes

Tags: oop, scala

The following code claims that Jack is employed in construction, but Jane is yet another victim of the rough economy:

```
abstract class Person(name: String) {

  case class Student(name: String, major: String) extends Person(name)

  override def toString(): String = this match {
    case Student(name, major) => name + " studies " + major
    case Worker(name, occupation) => name + " does " + occupation
    case _ => name + " is unemployed"
  }
}

case class Worker(name: String, job: String) extends Person(name)

object Narrator extends Person("Jake") {
  def main(args: Array[String]) {
    var friend: Person = new Student("Jane", "biology")
    println("My friend " + friend) //outputs "Jane is unemployed"
    friend = new Worker("Jack", "construction")
    println("My friend " + friend) //outputs "Jack does construction"
  }
}
```

Why does the match fail to recognize Jane as a Student?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Emil is entirely correct, but here's an example to make it clear:

```
scala> case class A(a: String) {
     |   case class B(b: String)
     |   def who(obj: Any) = obj match {
     |     case B(b) => println("I'm A("+a+").B("+b+").")
     |     case b: A#B => println("I'm B("+b+") from some A")
     |     case other => println("Who am I?")
     |   }
     | }
defined class A

scala> val a1 = A("a1")
a1: A = A(a1)

scala> val a2 = A("a2")
a2: A = A(a2)

scala> val b1= a1.B("b1")
b1: a1.B = B(b1)

scala> val b2 = a2.B("b2")
b2: a2.B = B(b2)

scala> a1 who b1
I'm A(a1).B(b1).

scala> a1 who b2
I'm B(B(b2)) from some A
```

To be more precise, this line:

```
case Student(name, major) => name + " studies " + major
```

really means

```
case this.Student(name, major) => name + " studies " + major
```

Unfortunately, while Jane was instantiated on Jake, `this` in Jane's case is pointing to Jane herself.

Answer (score 5):

What I believe is happening here is that the `Student` case class is being declared inside of `Person`.  Hence the `case Student` in the `toString` will only match `Student`s that are part of a particular `Person` instance.

If you move the `case class Student` to be parallel to the `case class Worker` (and then remove the unnecessary `extends Person("Jake")` from `object Narrator` ... which is only there so that the `new Student` wound up being a `Person$Student` specific to Jake), you will find Jane does indeed study biology.

Comment: Can you clarify what you mean by "a particular Person instance"?

Comment: Anyone know if this behaviour is documented anywhere?

Comment: @divider: `friend` is a `Narrator.Person`, but not a `friend.Person`.

Comment: @AlexeyRomanov To be more precise, it is a `Narrator#Person`.

Comment: @LuigiPlinge: This is a normal implication of lexical scoping.